# how to install roblox and roblox studio on raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3b+, games

please tell me how to install and run roblox and roblox studio on raspberry pi 3. it should not use pip or pip3.i have already tried using add/remove software app and sudo apt-get install roblox.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the options on [this link](https://www.roblox.com/#RobloxDeviceText) Roblox is not available for the Pi.

The corporate site states it’s only for PC, Mac, iOS, Android, Amazon Devices, Xbox One, Oculus Rift, and HTC Vive.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider installing LineageOS (Android) on your Raspberry Pi and the  installing Roblox via the  Google Play store.

https://www.lineageos.org/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Could you point to a Raspberry Pi version of Lineage?

Comment: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-android-lineageos/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing any linux distro, then install "wine" (program witch allows you to run windows applications) and maybe it will work.

Comment: You forgot to say "install an emulator to run x86 code on ARM, perhaps with a complete x86 virtual machine"

Answer (score -1):

I almost got it to work by going to this link web.roblox.com/library/41032326/kano and logging in.

Then I went to games and you click a game you want to play, then click the button that says download and install roblox. It then gives you a choice to open in a file. You then would click the open file button, then it lets you open file but i cant figure out how to open the file and install roblox player XD. You can still do anything but play games or create them.